# How to plot two bar graphs side by side with columns from different dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I want to plot two bar graphs side by side using matplotlib/seaborn for two countries Covid-19 confirmed cases: Italy and India for comparison. However after trying many methods I couldn't achieve the problem. Confirmed cases of both countries are coming from two different data frames.

[Data source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv)

I want to plot 'Dates' column on x-axis and 'Confirmed cases count' on y-axis.
Attaching images of my code for reference.
P.S: I am new to data visualization and pandas too.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import seaborn as sns
 df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid- 
 19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv', parse_dates = ['Date'])
 df.head(5)

 ind_cnfd = df[['Date', 'Country', 'Confirmed']]
 ind_cnfd = ind_cnfd[ind_cnfd['Country']=='India']
 italy_cnfd = df[['Date', 'Country', 'Confirmed']]
 italy_cnfd = italy_cnfd[italy_cnfd['Country'] == 'Italy']
```

Expected output kind of this: 
With dates on x-axis and confirmed cases on y-axis
[image]

Comment: I am happy to help you, but next time please include your code in the question instead of screenshots. This makes it easier for people to reproduce your code, and also means that if the images are lost, the question still makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Sure Derek. It's the first time i am putting up a question here. Will remember henceforth.

Comment: Awesome! I'll post my answer soon.

Comment: Updated my question. Please check and let me know any solution. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you can put together using matplotlib with seaborn. Feel free to play around with the axes settings, spacing, and so on by looking through matplotlib/seaborn documentation. Take note that I only did `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` if you want to run any of this code from your notebook. I didn't use seaborn by the way.

You can optionally display the confirmed cases on a log-based y scale with the line: `plt.yscale('log')`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv',
    parse_dates = ['Date'])

# select the Date, Country, Confirmed features from country, with reset of index
ind_cnfd = df[df.Country == 'India']
ind_cnfd = ind_cnfd[['Date', 'Confirmed']].reset_index(drop = True)
ind_cnfd = ind_cnfd.rename(columns = {'Confirmed': 'Confirmed Cases in India'})

italy_cnfd = df[df.Country == 'Italy']
italy_cnfd = italy_cnfd[['Date', 'Confirmed']].reset_index(drop = True)
italy_cnfd = italy_cnfd.rename(columns = {'Confirmed': 'Confirmed Cases in Italy'})

# combine dataframes together, turn the date column into the index
df_cnfd = pd.concat([ind_cnfd.drop(columns = 'Date'), italy_cnfd], axis = 1)
df_cnfd['Date'] = df_cnfd['Date'].dt.date
df_cnfd.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# make a grouped bar plot time series
ax = df_cnfd.plot.bar()

# show every other tick label
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)

# add titles, axis labels
plt.suptitle("Confirmed COVID-19 Cases over Time", fontsize = 15)
plt.xlabel("Dates")
plt.ylabel("Number of Confirmed Cases")
plt.tight_layout()
# plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works, Derek. But can i get the output as shown in my question? I may have framed my question incorrectly at first. My bad.

Comment: Oh I see, no need for subplots then. I would call what you want a "grouped barchart" for future reference. It might not look that good given the difference in confirmed cases between India and Italy, but happy to try!

Comment: A logscale on the y-axis could be an interesting alternative.

Comment: By the way, if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers